# Htaccess internal redirect for specific file not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I currently use the following htaccess code to remove all .php extensions:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteRule .* - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/?$ $1.php [L]
```

ive been trying to use the following htaccess code to internally redirect or add a hidden query parameter to a file

```
RewriteRule ^myfile/?([^/])?/?$ myfile.php?m=$1 [L]
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order of rules in .htaccess is important so your new rule should be above all other rules. This should be your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^myfile/?([^/])?/?$ myfile.php?m=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteRule .* - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/?$ $1.php [L]
```